# Python: String appended to a list doesn't show up

Tags: python, list

I'm experimenting with a sort of carpool application and strings won't be appended to the list. I'm a newbie programmer and can't seem to figure out the problem. Any advice even irrelevant to the question would be appreciated.

I've tried checking userInput and its value is 1 so from my understanding if userInput == 1: then the name should be appended to the parents list. However, the list 'parents' is completely empty.

```
import json

parents = []
children = []
name = input("What is your name? ")
user = []

userInput = input("Are you a parent or child? Please enter 1 or 2. ")
if userInput == "":
    print("Please select an option. ")
else:
    userInput == int(userInput)

if userInput == 1:
    parents.append('name')
elif userInput == 2:
    children.append('name')


with open('parentslist.txt', 'w') as file_object:
    json.dump(parents, file_object)

with open('parentslist.txt') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()

print(contents)

print("\n")

for i in range(len(parents)):
    print(parents[i])
```

> > > What is your name? 
> > >       John Smith
> > >       Are you a parent or child? Please enter 1 or 2.
> > >       1
> > >       []

From my understanding, the code should print:

John Smith

[John Smith]

the first line being the contents of the json file after it was written and the second being the output of the for loop that prints the contents of the list 'parents'.

Comment: `userInput == int(userInput)` only checks for equality but doesn't set "userInput". Therefore it is the string input yet, not an integer number.

Comment: You have: parents.append('name') and children.append('name') --should change 'name' to name since you want to append the variable name not the string 'name'

Comment: Thanks a lot, my code finally outputs John Smith

[John Smith]

Comment: I saw that just now and I fixed it. Thank you Darryl

Comment: Another issue is you are using: contents = file_object.read().  This means contents is a string (not a list of parents).  Since you used json.dump(parents, file_object) to save the parent list, you should use with open('parentslist.txt') as json_file:
    content = json.load(json_file) to retrieve the list.  [For further details](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues in the code :

- Use "=" instead of "==" for assigning the converted value `userInput = int(userInput)` or you can instead use `int(userInput) == 1` in the if condition
- Use name without quotes for the append `parents.append(name)` in order to output the actual name instead of the string "name"

You may also use a while loop for repeating the "*Are you a parent or child? Please enter 1 or 2.*" until the user provides a valid input (1 or 2).

Cheers!